# Word splitting within backticks

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, backticks

What is the difference between line #2 and line #4 in the script ("foo bar" (without quotes) folder exists):

```
FOOBAR="foo bar"
echo `ls -la "$FOOBAR"`
args="-la \"$FOOBAR\""
echo `ls $args`
```

Output:

```
total 0 drwxr-xr-x 2 tervlad LD\Domain Users 68 15 ноя 11:47 . drwxr-xr-x 7 tervlad LD\Domain Users 238 16 ноя 18:01 ..
ls: "foo: No such file or directory
ls: bar": No such file or directory
```

How can I get line #4 working properly?

Comment: The difference is: quotes.

Comment: `$FOOBAR` is expanded in the assignment to args. Also quotes are interpreted before `$` expansion, so quotes are literal parts of the expanded string.

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is directly on-point.

Comment: ...and the backticks have nothing whatsoever to do with it. You'd have **precisely** the same behavior from `ls $args` with no backticks involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$FOOBAR` is expanded in the assignment to args. Also quotes are interpreted before `$` expansion, so quotes are literal parts of the expanded string.

Just use an array.

```
args=( "-la" "$FOOBAR" )
ls "${args[@]}"
```